# How to load a layout XML file from a different page

Tags: layout, magento2.2

On the "Saved Payment Methods" page, customers can look (and interact with) their saved cards.  This happens on the `vault_cards_listaction` page.  I want to build a *separate* page that interacts with the vaulted cards.

However, in order for me to render a token, I need a `Magento\Vault\Block\AbstractTokenRenderer`.  The current way this works is that modules with vault support add their CardRenderer to the layout page.  For example, Braintree has the following file at `module-braintree/view/frontend/layout/vault_cards_listaction.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="vault.cards.list">
            <block class="Magento\Braintree\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="braintree.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="vault.token.list">
            <block class="Magento\Braintree\Block\Customer\PayPal\VaultTokenRenderer" name="braintree_paypal.token.renderer" template="Magento_Braintree::paypal/vault_token.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

However, **I want to render cards/tokens on a *different* page (not on the `vault_cards_listaction` page)**.   This means I don't have access (AFAIK) to the `vault.cards.list` block, so I can't render the list of cards.

My best idea so far is to make my own custom `vault.cards.list` block, but that means that I have to write custom XML for every payment gateway that supports vaults (which doesn't play nice with 3rd party modules that use Magento_Vault).

Is there any way I can automatically grab the renderer for a particular token type?